# Which goddess (Ishta devi/Kula devi) sits legs folded & holding shiva linga?

Tags: temple, identification-request, goddess, idols

Goddess sitting and holding shivling on one hand. And sitting  folding both legs.Please help me find this goddess and details about the temple I'll find her if possible.

Comment: Which goddess is she? Do you have a picture and where did you see the picture?

Comment: Quite possibly she is goddess Parvati herself , wife of lord Shiva. She is shown in lots of pictures holding Shiva-Linga in either one or in both hands

Answer (score 6):

It is Istha Kameswari Devi having four hands, in two hands having lotus flower and in other two hands one have shiva linga and other one have japa Mala. It is a form of devi Parvati. The very special thing is when you apply kumkum on the forehead of the Idol of the goddess you will feel like touching human skin in fact the Idol is of stone.

It is located in kurnool District, approximately 15km from srisailam, Andhra Pradesh.

[image: Ista Kameswari Devi]

Answer (score 1):

This is goddess Nagalamba. Can you help me find the temple of this goddess or any other information would really be useful. Kindly help me out.

Comment: Welcome to HSE! Part of your answer can be a different question altogether. Please remove the part and add authentic source to support your answer.